# more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: java, android-studio

I have read many references for solve this issue but, didn't get any solution
this my gridlle writen

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.indrasuandi.testandroid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

what can I edit for this gradle, to solve my error?

Answer (score 0):

update to the latest

```
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

and change the gradle plugin to the latest as well i.e.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```